# Why value I'm trying to invoke method setVisibility() is null?

Tags: java, android

I have this stack trace from `Firebase Craslytics`:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>   com.accenture.vrmobile.BaseActivity.setDrawerVisibility(BaseActivity.java:497)

It's reporting crash in this method:

```
    public void setDrawerVisibility(Boolean visible) {
    if (mButtonActionBarLeft == null)
        mButtonActionBarLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_left);
    if (mButtonActionBarRight == null)
        mButtonActionBarRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_right);
    if (visible) {
        mButtonActionBarLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //crashes at this line
        mButtonActionBarRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mButtonActionBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonActionBarRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I had this crash before, so I added these lines to the method:

```
if (mButtonActionBarLeft == null)
        mButtonActionBarLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_left);
    if (mButtonActionBarRight == null)
        mButtonActionBarRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_right);
```

But it's still crashing and reporting `nullPointerException`. mButtonActionBarLeft and mButtonActionBarRight are buttons that opens/closes navigation drawer.
I have no idea why is this happening. Maybe someone has experience with this? 
Thank you!

P.S. I was never able to reproduce this crash, it happens really rarely. I only have stack trace from `Firebase`.

Comment: check R.id.button_actionbar_left is their in layout

Comment: Normally it is. It's a navigation drawer button. But as I wrote before I can't reproduce this crash.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Hey, @SandraBoguša Any solution?  :o

Answer (score 0):

Create the instance of your `ImageView` into your Activity `onCreate()` callback

also make sure that you are creating instance which is present in your layout file with given id.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        if (mButtonActionBarLeft == null)
            mButtonActionBarLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_left);
        if (mButtonActionBarRight == null)
            mButtonActionBarRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_actionbar_right);
}
```

Learn more about NullPointerException:-[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you! But I'll already have that. And crash is still happening

Answer (score 0):

you must add View as input of function. for example,

```
public void setVisible(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
setVisible(toolbarText);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!
I don't really see how this changes anything. Why do I need to add view to input?

Comment: because you can change all Views visibility. this is better

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if (visible) {
        if(mButtonActionBarLeft.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
            mButtonActionBarLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(mButtonActionBarRight.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
            mButtonActionBarRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        if(mButtonActionBarLeft.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            mButtonActionBarLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        if(mButtonActionBarRight.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            mButtonActionBarRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is, that you can't call get/set visibility on Null. What you are going here is just adding more of those calls.